# Ayuda registro de huella en Vb

Tags: mysql, vb

Tengo un problema: cuando intenté crear el botón de buscar la huella que tengo registrada en la base de datos, ya no me funciona nada, solo me sale el mensaje de `"No se pudo inicializar la captura"`, pero ahora no se donde tengo el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Text
Imports DPFP
Imports DPFP.Capture
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Implements DPFP.Capture.EventHandler

    Private Captura As DPFP.Capture.Capture
    Private enroller As DPFP.Processing.Enrollment
    Private Delegate Sub _delegadoMuestra(ByVal text As String)
    Private Delegate Sub _delegadoControles()
    Private template As DPFP.Template

    Private Sub mostrarVeces(ByVal texto As String)
        If (lblDedo.InvokeRequired) Then
            Dim deleg As New _delegadoMuestra(AddressOf mostrarVeces)
            Me.Invoke(deleg, New Object() {texto})
        Else
            lblDedo.Text = texto
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub modificarControles()
        If (btnGuardar.InvokeRequired) Then
            Dim deleg As New _delegadoControles(AddressOf modificarControles)
            Me.Invoke(deleg, New Object() {})
        Else
            btnGuardar.Enabled = True
            txtNombre.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub Init()
        Try
            Captura = New Capture()
            If Not Captura Is Nothing Then
                Captura.EventHandler = Me
                enroller = New DPFP.Processing.Enrollment()
                Dim text As New StringBuilder()
                text.AppendFormat("Por favor coloca la Huella {0} veces", enroller.FeaturesNeeded)
                lblDedo.Text = text.ToString()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("No se puede instanciar la captura")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("No se pudo inicializar la captura")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Sub iniciarCaptura()
        If Not Captura Is Nothing Then
            Try
                Captura.StartCapture()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo iniciar la captura")
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub pararCaptura()
        If Not Captura Is Nothing Then
            Try
                Captura.StopCapture()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo detener la captura")
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnComplete(Capture As Object, ReaderSerialNumber As String, Sample As Sample) Implements EventHandler.OnComplete
        ponerImagen(ConvertirSampleaMapadeBits(Sample))
        Procesar(Sample)
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnFingerGone(Capture As Object, ReaderSerialNumber As String) Implements EventHandler.OnFingerGone

    End Sub

    Public Sub OnFingerTouch(Capture As Object, ReaderSerialNumber As String) Implements EventHandler.OnFingerTouch

    End Sub

    Public Sub OnReaderConnect(Capture As Object, ReaderSerialNumber As String) Implements EventHandler.OnReaderConnect

    End Sub

    Public Sub OnReaderDisconnect(Capture As Object, ReaderSerialNumber As String) Implements EventHandler.OnReaderDisconnect

    End Sub

    Public Sub OnSampleQuality(Capture As Object, ReaderSerialNumber As String, CaptureFeedback As CaptureFeedback) Implements EventHandler.OnSampleQuality
        'EventHandler.OnSampleQuality()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Init()
        iniciarCaptura()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
        pararCaptura()
    End Sub

    Protected Function ConvertirSampleaMapadeBits(ByVal Sample As DPFP.Sample) As Bitmap
        Dim convertidor As New DPFP.Capture.SampleConversion() 'es una variable de tipo conversor de un DPFP.Sample
        Dim mapaBits As Bitmap = Nothing
        convertidor.ConvertToPicture(Sample, mapaBits)
        Return mapaBits
    End Function

    Private Sub ponerImagen(ByVal bmp)
        imgHuella.Image = bmp
    End Sub

    Protected Function extraerCaracteristicas(ByVal Sample As DPFP.Sample, ByVal Purpose As DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose) As DPFP.FeatureSet
        Dim extractor As New DPFP.Processing.FeatureExtraction()
        Dim alimentacion As DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback = DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback.None
        Dim caracteristicas As New DPFP.FeatureSet()
        extractor.CreateFeatureSet(Sample, Purpose, alimentacion, caracteristicas)
        If (alimentacion = DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback.Good) Then
            Return caracteristicas
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function

    Protected Sub Procesar(ByVal Sample As DPFP.Sample)
        Dim caracteristicas As DPFP.FeatureSet = extraerCaracteristicas(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Enrollment)
        If (Not caracteristicas Is Nothing) Then
            Try
                enroller.AddFeatures(caracteristicas)
            Finally
                Dim text As New StringBuilder()
                text.AppendFormat("Por favor coloca la Huella {0} veces", enroller.FeaturesNeeded)
                mostrarVeces(text.ToString())
                Select Case enroller.TemplateStatus
                    Case DPFP.Processing.Enrollment.Status.Ready
                        template = enroller.Template
                        pararCaptura()
                        modificarControles()
                    Case DPFP.Processing.Enrollment.Status.Failed
                        enroller.Clear()
                        pararCaptura()
                        iniciarCaptura()
                End Select
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnGuardar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGuardar.Click
        Dim builderconex As New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()
        builderconex.Server = "localhost"
        builderconex.UserID = "root"
        builderconex.Password = ""
        builderconex.Database = "digitalpersona"
        Dim conexion As New MySqlConnection(builderconex.ToString())
        conexion.Open()
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()
        cmd = conexion.CreateCommand
        If (txtNombre.Text.ToString().Equals("")) Then
            MessageBox.Show("No pueden quedar campos varios")
        Else
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre,huella) VALUES (?,?)"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nombre", txtNombre.Text.ToString())
            Using fm As New MemoryStream(template.Bytes)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("huella", fm.ToArray())
            End Using
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            conexion.Close()
            conexion.Dispose()
            MessageBox.Show("Registro Guardado")
            btnGuardar.Enabled = False
            txtNombre.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnBuscar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBuscar.Click
        pararCaptura()
        Dim ventanabuscar As New Consulta()
        ventanabuscar.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Leave
        pararCaptura()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
        Init()
        iniciarCaptura()
    End Sub
End Class
```

este es el código para cuando vaya a buscar la huella en mi base de datos

```
Imports System.IO
Imports DPFP
Imports DPFP.Capture
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Consulta
    Implements DPFP.Capture.EventHandler
    Private template As DPFP.Template
    Private Captura As DPFP.Capture.Capture
    Private verificador As DPFP.Verification.Verification

    Protected Overridable Sub Init()
        Try
            Captura = New Capture()
            If Not Captura Is Nothing Then
                Captura.EventHandler = Me
                verificador = New Verification.Verification()
                template = New Template()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("No se puede instanciar la captura")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("No se pudo inicializar la captura")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Sub iniciarCaptura()
        If Not Captura Is Nothing Then
            Try
                Captura.StartCapture()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo iniciar la captura" + ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub


    Protected Sub pararCaptura()
        If Not Captura Is Nothing Then
            Try
                Captura.StopCapture()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo detener la captura")
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ponerImagen(ByVal bmp)
        imagenHuella.Image = bmp
    End Sub

    Protected Function ConvertirSampleaMapadeBits(ByVal Sample As DPFP.Sample) As Bitmap
        Dim convertidor As New DPFP.Capture.SampleConversion() 'es una variable de tipo conversor de un DPFP.Sample
        Dim mapaBits As Bitmap = Nothing
        convertidor.ConvertToPicture(Sample, mapaBits)
        Return mapaBits
    End Function

    Protected Function extraerCaracteristicas(ByVal Sample As DPFP.Sample, ByVal Purpose As DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose) As DPFP.FeatureSet
        Dim extractor As New DPFP.Processing.FeatureExtraction()
        Dim alimentacion As DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback = DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback.None
        Dim caracteristicas As New DPFP.FeatureSet()
        extractor.CreateFeatureSet(Sample, Purpose, alimentacion, caracteristicas)
        If (alimentacion = DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback.Good) Then
            Return caracteristicas
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function

    'verificado hasta aca 

    Public Sub OnComplete(Capture As Object, ReaderSerialNumber As String, Sample As Sample) Implements EventHandler.OnComplete
        ponerImagen(ConvertirSampleaMapadeBits(Sample))
        Dim caracteristicas As DPFP.FeatureSet = extraerCaracteristicas(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Verification)
        If Not caracteristicas Is Nothing Then
            Dim result As New DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result()
            Dim builderconex As New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()
            builderconex.Server = "localhost"
            builderconex.UserID = "root"
            builderconex.Password = "jorge159302"
            builderconex.Database = "digitalpersona"
            Dim conexion As New MySqlConnection(builderconex.ToString())
            conexion.Open()
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()
            cmd = conexion.CreateCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM usuarios"
            Dim read As MySqlDataReader
            read = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            Dim verificado As Boolean = False
            Dim nombre As String = ""
            While (read.Read())
                Dim memoria As New MemoryStream(CType(read("huella"), Byte()))
                template.DeSerialize(memoria.ToArray())
                verificador.Verify(caracteristicas, template, result)
                If (result.Verified) Then
                    nombre = read("nombre")
                    verificado = True
                    Exit While
                End If
            End While
            If (verificado) Then
                MessageBox.Show(nombre)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("No se encontro ningun registro")
            End If
            read.Dispose()
            cmd.Dispose()
            conexion.Close()
            conexion.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnFingerGone(Capture As Object, ReaderSerialNumber As String) Implements EventHandler.OnFingerGone

    End Sub

    Public Sub OnFingerTouch(Capture As Object, ReaderSerialNumber As String) Implements EventHandler.OnFingerTouch

    End Sub

    Public Sub OnReaderConnect(Capture As Object, ReaderSerialNumber As String) Implements EventHandler.OnReaderConnect

    End Sub

    Public Sub OnReaderDisconnect(Capture As Object, ReaderSerialNumber As String) Implements EventHandler.OnReaderDisconnect

    End Sub

    Public Sub OnSampleQuality(Capture As Object, ReaderSerialNumber As String, CaptureFeedback As CaptureFeedback) Implements EventHandler.OnSampleQuality

    End Sub

    Private Sub Consulta_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Init()
        iniciarCaptura()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Consulta_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        pararCaptura()
    End Sub
End Class
```